# Loop through the second column of WPF ListView and retrieve value of ComboBox in each row

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, combobox, listbox

I have a two-column ListView with CheckBoxes in the first column and ComboBoxes in the second column.  I need to loop through the ComoboBoxes in the second column and retrieve the selected values (or indexes) from each ComboBox, along with some index or identifier of the ComboBox, and put the values in an array.  For example, the layout looks like this:

```
COLUMN 1  COLUMN 2
========  ========
ChBx 1    Combo1
ChBx 2    Combo2
```

I need to grab the SelectedValue or SelectedIndex of each ComboBox in the second column and put it into an array in the right order.  But, what I've found on the internet is to use: myListView.Items(0).SubItems(1).Text, to loop through the second column.  However, my second column contains a ComboBox and I want its' value (not some Text property).  Any ideas?  My XAML markup is below.

```
            <ListView IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Margin="0,0,10,10" Name="patternList" Height="139" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="112" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="1" Background="White" >
                 <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridView.Columns>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Pattern">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding outContent}" 
                                                  ToolTip="{Binding outToolTip}"
                                                  IsThreeState="False"
                                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=outIsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Freq" Width="55">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ComboBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
                                                  Height="14" 
                                                  Padding="0" 
                                                  SelectionChanged="FrequencyChanged_OnSelectionChanged"
                                                  FontSize="10">
                                            <ComboBoxItem Content="0%"/>
                                            <ComboBoxItem Content="10%"/>
                                            <ComboBoxItem Content="20%"/>
                                            <ComboBoxItem Content="30%"/>
                                            <ComboBoxItem Content="40%"/>
                                            <ComboBoxItem Content="50%"/>
                                            <ComboBoxItem Content="60%"/>
                                            <ComboBoxItem Content="70%"/>
                                            <ComboBoxItem Content="80%"/>
                                            <ComboBoxItem Content="90%"/>
                                            <ComboBoxItem Content="100%"/>
                                        </ComboBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView.Columns>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
   </ListView>
```

Comment: Bind SelectedValue to a property in your ViewModel. And in the Setter of that property, also update the collection.

Comment: Thanks.  If I understand correctly, I can add another property, let's say "Weighting" to Checkbox in the first column, and set a property in the ComboBox in the second column, like this: SelectedValue="{Binding Weighting, Mode=TwoWay}".  Is that right?  But I'm not sure how to do the Setter part - can you show how?

Comment: @AnjumSKhan - your suggestion did it.  But, I don't know how to mark your Answer correct.  If you make it an Answer (instead of just a Comment), I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind `SelectedValue` to a property in your ViewModel. And in the Setter of that property, also update the collection.

Second approach, in your `FrequencyChanged_OnSelectionChanged` event handler. You can keep updating your collection there too.

Comment: Cool, thanks - I have a follow-up question, but I reposted it since it's a bit different.  But here's the link, in case you want to take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34242718/update-wpf-checkbox-in-listview-from-enabled-to-disabled-when-clicked-inotify-n

Comment: Btw, got my app working, but have a new question posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34251149/dynamically-populate-combobox-within-a-wpf-listview-with-items

Comment: @swabygw Post such messages in chat room mentioning my name there.

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective it would be better to generate items for the combobox in list item viewmodel, and bind to selected item in that view model. Below is the code that illustrates the approach.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="ComboboxesInGrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ComboboxesInGrid"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}" Margin="0,0,10,10" Name="patternList" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="1" Background="White" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Pattern" Width="100">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding outContent}" 
                                                  ToolTip="{Binding outToolTip}"
                                                  IsThreeState="False"
                                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=outIsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Freq" Width="155">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ComboBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
                                                  Height="14" 
                                                  Padding="0" 
                                                  SelectedItem="{Binding outComboSelected}"
                                                  ItemsSource="{Binding outComboValues}"
                                                  FontSize="10">

                                    </ComboBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding SelectedComboItems}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;


namespace ComboboxesInGrid
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<ListItemViewModel> _listItems = new ObservableCollection<ListItemViewModel>();

        public string SelectedComboItems
        {
            get { return String.Join(",", _listItems.Select(li => $"{li.outContent}-{li.outIsChecked}-{li.outComboSelected}")); }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ListItemViewModel> ListItems
        {
            get { return _listItems; }
            set { _listItems = value; OnProperyChanged(); }
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            AddListItem(new ListItemViewModel() { outContent = "ChBx 1 ", outToolTip="Tooooool", outIsChecked = false, outComboSelected="30%" });
            AddListItem(new ListItemViewModel() { outContent = "ChBx 2 ", outComboSelected = "70%" });

        }

        private void AddListItem(ListItemViewModel item)
        {
            item.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => OnProperyChanged(nameof(SelectedComboItems));
            _listItems.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public class ListItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private string _outContent;

        public string outContent
        {
            get { return _outContent; }
            set { _outContent = value; OnProperyChanged(); }
        }


        private string _outToolTip;
        public string outToolTip
        {
            get { return _outToolTip; }
            set { _outToolTip = value; OnProperyChanged(); }
        }

        private bool? _outIsChecked;
        public bool? outIsChecked
        {
            get { return _outIsChecked; }
            set { _outIsChecked = value; OnProperyChanged(); }
        }

        private string _outComboSelected;
        public string outComboSelected
        {
            get { return _outComboSelected; }
            set { _outComboSelected = value; OnProperyChanged(); }
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> outComboValues
        {
            get
            {
                return Enumerable.Range(0, 11).Select(i => $"{i*10}%");
            }
        }
    }

    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected void OnProperyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Since it's only a few items in each Combobox, I chose a simpler approach, but, if my list were much bigger, I would certainly give this a shot.

Comment: NP. Typically it is recommended to use MVVM pattern with WPF, in order to separate UI from application logic. Your percentage values will be handled somehow, so to extract them you'll need to deal with ComboBoxItem in your Business Logic layer. In general it is not good to use UI objects in your business logic code. But of course it is up to you to decide what is better for your application.

Comment: I've posted a related question, in case you have a chance to take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34242718/update-wpf-checkbox-in-listview-from-enabled-to-disabled-when-clicked-inotify-n